# Merge two arrays outside their functions using Promise.all

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge two arrays by their id (event.id) into one array. I faced with a problem, I don't understand how to merge these arrays outside their functions. I know that there is a way to do it using `Promise.all`, but don't know how to do it. Thank you for your time.

```
function getpinnacle() {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var options = {sportId: 29};
    pinnacle.getFixtures(options, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      var pinnFixtures = [];
      body.league.forEach(function(leagues){
        leagues.events.forEach(function(event){ 
          if (event.status == 'O'){
            pinnFixtures.push({
              'id': event.id,
              'homeTeamName': event.home,
              'awayTeamName': event.away
            });
          };    
        });
      });
      resolve(pinnFixtures);
    });

    var options = {sportId: 29, oddsFormat: "DECIMAL"};
    pinnacle.getOdds(options, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) throw new Error(err);
      var pinnOdds = [];
      body.leagues.forEach(function(league){
        league.events.forEach(function(event){
          event.periods.forEach(function(period){
            if (period.moneyline !== undefined) {
              pinnOdds.push({
                'id': event.id,
                'homeTeamOdds': period.moneyline.home,
                'drawOdds': period.moneyline.draw,
                'awayTeamOdds': period.moneyline.away
              }); 
            };
          });
        });
      });
      resolve(pinnOdds);
    });
  });

}
module.exports = getpinnacle;
```

Comment: You may create any array of promises. and then push all your promises in that array and then you can specify promise.all();

Comment: please read it from here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have a context where you have both arrays available to you, you can wrap each callback in a promise, and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for the results:

```
function getpinnacle() {
    var options = {sportId: 29};
    const fixtures = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      pinnacle.getFixtures(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        var pinnFixtures = [];
        body.league.forEach(function(leagues){
          leagues.events.forEach(function(event){ 
            if (event.status == 'O'){
              pinnFixtures.push({
                'id': event.id,
                'homeTeamName': event.home,
                'awayTeamName': event.away
              });
            };    
          });
        });
        resolve(pinnFixtures);
      });
    });

    var options = {sportId: 29, oddsFormat: "DECIMAL"};
    const odds = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      pinnacle.getOdds(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
        var pinnOdds = [];
        body.leagues.forEach(function(league){
          league.events.forEach(function(event){
            event.periods.forEach(function(period){
              if (period.moneyline !== undefined) {
                pinnOdds.push({
                  'id': event.id,
                  'homeTeamOdds': period.moneyline.home,
                  'drawOdds': period.moneyline.draw,
                  'awayTeamOdds': period.moneyline.away
                }); 
              };
            });
          });
        });
        resolve(pinnOdds);
      });
    });
    return Promise.all([fixtures, odds]);
}
```

After that you can call `getPinnacle().then(function(results){...})` where results is an array `[fixtures, odds]`.

Comment: Where it should be extra logic that fixtures concat odds by id and show only those fixtures which have odds?

Comment: You would write that in the `then` clause of the returned promise, either in the function (last line) or on the return value.

Comment: Take a good look at the last line I wrote, it's how you use it. Here's a more full example: `getPinnacle().then(function(results){ doSomethingWithOdds(results[1])}`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to refactor your code is to break `getFixtures` and `getOdds` into two separate functions, each of which returns a promise.  Then getPinnacle would `return Promise.all(getFixtures(), getOdds())`

Answer (score 0):

you may use promise.all like this

```
function getpinnacle() {
   var promises = [];
   var fixturePromise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
          ///add your code here and resolve from inside you getFixture method
   });
promises.push(fixturePromise);
var oddPromise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
//add your getOdds method here and resolve this promise too
 });

 promise.push(oddPromise);

 Promise.all(promises).then( (response) => {
 var fixtureResponse = response[0];
var oddResponse = response[1];
//add your extra logic here
});
}
```